# Parsing an array based on keyword AND array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, filter

Suppose I have an array and 2 variables; one that's just a simple string, and one that's an array of string values:

```
var street = "Fernwood Avenue";
var fips = ["34011", "34007"];

var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];
```

What I want to do here is iterate through my test_array and find just the subarrays that match for street in sub_array[6] AND have a match for sub_array[3] in the fips list (["34011", "34007"]). Is there a way to use filter (or any other method) to achieve this and return the results below?

```
var new_array = [["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"], 
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"]];
```

*Bonus: Suppose there is a function where the street and fips come in as a list argument where the street name will ALWAYS be there but the fips values may or may not. So,

```
var keyword = ["Fernwood Avenue", "34011", "34007"];
```

or

```
var keyword = ["Fernwood Avenue"];
```

or

```
var keyword = ["Fernwood Avenue", "34011"];
```

with a function(s) something like this (*This does not work for scenario 1)

```
function matcher(array1, array2) {
    return array1.every(value => array2.includes(value));
}

function array_parser(array, keywords) {
    return array.filter(values => matcher(keywords, values));
}

var new_array = array_parser(test_array, keywords);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is a simple filter

```js
var street = "Fernwood Avenue";
var fips = ["34011", "34007"];

var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];

const result = test_array.filter( values => values[6] == street && fips.includes(values[3]))
console.log(result);
```

For your bonus question:

```js
var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];


function matcher(array1, array2) {
    const street = array1[0];
    const fips = array1.slice(1);
    return array2[6] == street && (fips.length === 0 || fips.includes(array2[3]));
}

function array_parser(array, keywords) {
    return array.filter(values => matcher(keywords, values));
}

console.log(array_parser(test_array, ["Fernwood Avenue", "34011", "34007"]));

console.log(array_parser(test_array, ["Fernwood Avenue", "34011"]));

console.log(array_parser(test_array, ["Fernwood Avenue"]));
```

Comment: All of these answers are great. I went went this one because the matcher function made the most since in the context of my larger application. Thnx all!

Answer (score 1):

This answers the first part of the question

```js
var street = "Fernwood Avenue";
var fips = ["34011", "34007"];

var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];

console.log(test_array.filter(e => e[6]===street && (fips.indexOf(e[3]) > -1)))
```

This answers the second part of the question, but I'm not sure how readable it is, to put it simply, the second parameter of `Array.indexOf()` specifies the starting index for searching inside the list. But if inside `keyword` you only specify the street, it would always return -1 since there is no second element to start the search from.

Adding a check on `keyword.length` solves this by always returning true when length is 1 (a.k.a, ignore the filtering by fip)

```js
var keyword = ["Fernwood Avenue","34011"];

var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];

console.log(test_array.filter(e => (e[6]===keyword[0]) && (keyword.length > 1 ? keyword.indexOf(e[3],1) > -1 : true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two variables: you can take the function and check known indexes against each in a [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). If you want to match everything when an empty list is passed, then you can just make a mock lookup that allows everything:

```js
function findStuff(array, street, fips) {
  const streetIndex = 6;
  const fipsIndex = 3;
  
  let fipsLookup;
  if (fips.length > 0)
    fipsLookup = new Set(fips);
  else
    fipsLookup = { has() { return true; } };

  return array.filter(item => 
    item[streetIndex] === street && fipsLookup.has(item[fipsIndex])
  )
}

var test_array =[
  ["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
  ["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]
];

var street = "Fernwood Avenue";
var fips = ["34011", "34007"]

let result = findStuff(test_array, street, fips);
for (const item of result)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); //more concise display
  
console.log("-----");

fips = []

result = findStuff(test_array, street, fips);
for (const item of result)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); //more concise display
```

> *Bonus: Suppose there is a function where the street and fips come in as a list argument where the street name will ALWAYS be there but the fips values may or may not.

Change the function declaration from this:

```
function findStuff(array, street, fips)
```

to this:

```
function findStuff(array, [street, ...fips])
```

In order to make use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) to get the first item as street and [collect the rest into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) as `fips`. The body of the function remains the same.

```js
function findStuff(array, [street, ...fips]) {
  const streetIndex = 6;
  const fipsIndex = 3;
  
  let fipsLookup;
  if (fips.length > 0)
    fipsLookup = new Set(fips);
  else
    fipsLookup = { has() { return true; } };

  return array.filter(item => 
    item[streetIndex] === street && fipsLookup.has(item[fipsIndex])
  )
}

var test_array =[
  ["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
  ["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]
];

var keywords = ["Fernwood Avenue", "34011", "34007"];

let result = findStuff(test_array, keywords);
for (const item of result)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); //more concise display
  
console.log("-----");

keywords = ["Fernwood Avenue"];

result = findStuff(test_array, keywords);
for (const item of result)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); //more concise display
```